# Randomizing the text of a question in XLSForm

Tags: odk

I am designing a survey in XLSForm, not in Excel. I need to randomize not only the order of choices, but also the text of the questions. Some questions are made of four sentences A, B, C and D. I need them displayed in random order.

I thought of using a calculate field with a random number. But there are 24 combinations for 4 sentences and I cannot possibly make that many fields.

Comment: Did you try `=ROUND(RANDBETWEEN(0,24),0) to get that 24 combinations?

Comment: I cant't really use Excel functions, just XLSForm functions.

Comment: Ok, so you shouldn´t tag your question on Excel, right? Did you check [this](http://xlsform.org/en/#randomize-choices)?

Comment: Right, but I couldn't find the tag for XLSForm and I'm not allowed to create them. That function allows me to randomize choices as I wrote in OP, but not questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach might work.

1. Use question type xml-external to add an external data XML file with your 4 texts in different nodes. Call this 'mytexts' eg. The structure could be something like this:

```xml
<root>
 <text>first text</text>
 <text>second text</text>
 <text>third text</text>
 <text>fourth text</text>
</root>
```

2. In the label of your question use `join(" ", randomize(instance('mytexts')/root/text))`